# Bootstrap css: body not containing all elements on page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have added Bootstrap Sass to a Rails project and I'm trying to redesign its home page. The issue I am facing is that the background style I have added to my `<body>` element only has effect on the part of the page that is initially visible upon loading the page. The page actually scrolls down to show additional elements, which are all enclosed in `<body>`. To solve this, I enclosed everything in `<body>` with a `<div class="clearit"> .......</div>`. In the CSS, I did two things: I first tried using the `overflow:auto` property, but that did not have the desired effect. I have also tried the following:

```
.clearit {
    zoom: 1.0;
    clear: both;
}

.clearit:after
{
    zoom: 1.0;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Even with this, the browser seems to think that my `<body>` is simply the 100% of the part of the page that is initially visible upon loading, not the entire page till the bottom of the scroll bar. I have foraged through online solutions and guides, and tried multiple approaches for several days, but haven't yet found one that works. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be helpful, but are you trying to accomplish something like I've done here?:
http://www.danhendricks.com

Rather than setting the  to 100%, I just set the top  to height=100% and set the background image. See the .intro-section class here for an example:
http://www.danhendricks.com/wp-content/themes/single-page-modified/style.css

```
.intro-section {
    background: url(images/my-background-image.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px; /* So content isn't covered up by the header bar */
}
```

Though I don't have scrolling on this page, an easier to read example may be found here. It uses the exact same technique, just minus the header bar and and sections below the .intro-section:
http://www.nimbium.com

If I'm off base with what you are looking for, I apologize. I'm also new here so I apologize if this isn't a properly formatted response. I was just trying to offer some quick help.